# Image border does not work in Outlook 2010/2007

Tags: image, outlook, border

Here is the issue: I would like a white border on the picture, but when I send it to my outlook 2007 or 2010, it's not showing. Here is the code for the image in question:

`<img src="my.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="220" border="3" style="border:3px solid #FFF;" />`

Is there a fix out there for this issue? I feel like I've tried everything and nothing's worked.

This did render a border, but it's not an ideal solution because there is a space between the image and border.

```
<table width="220" height="220" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:3px solid #FFF;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="my.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="220" border="0" title="70's Styled House and Pool" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have to wrap it in something. How about Span:

```
s = "<html><body>" _
& "<span style='display:inline-block;padding:5px;border:5px solid #fff;'>" _
& "<img src='z:\docs\image1.jpg' alt='' width=220 height=220></span>" _
& "</body></html> "

Set oEmail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

oEmail.HTMLBody = s
oEmail.Display
```

Comment: this worked but there is a space between pic and border it can be seen. But thanks it saved me doing this

Comment: The space between pic and border is due to padding:5px; you can set "padding:0px;" and also add 'width and height' in the span inline css...

Comment: `display` property isn't supported in Outlook

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the SPAN solution to work (I suspect because of extra code added by my CMS).

My solution was to wrap the image in a table with cellpadding set to the desired border width, and bgcolor set to the desired border colour. Hardly semantic, but that's Outlook's fault.

Answer (score -2):

One of your issues is that hex color short-hand isn't supported in email. So you should be using all six hex digits.

```html
<img
    src="http://example.com/image.jpg" 
    alt="" 
    width="220" 
    height="220" 
    border="3"
    style="border:3px solid #ffffff;" />
```